# WordPress with React: Saving and Using Data Collected with fetch

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to do a hopefully basic thing with react, which is access an endpoint created by my locally installed WordPress website so that I can use that data and render it in a way I like.

I am trying to set the state to the data but alsough it can be printed to the console in the `componentWillMount()` function, the state `posts` remains empty. I can `console.log` the data from that function but I cannot set the state and then use it in the `render` function.  My code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Widget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            posts: []
        };
    }


    componentWillMount() {
      const theUrl = "http://localhost:8888/test-site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";

      fetch(theUrl)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response =>
        this.setState({
          posts: response
        })
      )
    }


    render() {
      console.log('render posts: ' + this.state.posts);

        return (
            <div>
              <h1>React Widget</h1>
                <p>posts:</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Widget.propTypes = {
  wpObject: PropTypes.object
};
```

Console:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1

react-dom.development.js:21258 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://.me/react-devtools

react-dom.development.js:21258 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://.me/react-devtools

Widget.jsx:28 render posts: 

jquery.loader.js:2 running on http://localhost:8888/test-site/

Widget.jsx:28 render posts: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

the second to last line in the console has a collapse arrow next to it and I can see that those are in fact the posts with all of their correct information.  Why can I not set the state to the data being returned by `fetch()`?

Comment: `posts: console.log(response)` is wrong there. remove the `console.log` call

Comment: @Felix so that did not fix it, but it looks like doing that fixed part of the problem because now the response IS passed to the `render()` function but as an unprintable object.  I'll update the code and console output in my question.

Comment: Well just add return a value from the object in the render function.

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEES! Ok that did it, its an array of objects I think.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React has a special function `setState()` to set a components state (for class components). So instead of a direct assignment

```
this.state = {
    value: 'foo2',
    posts: data.value,
};
```

use

```
this.setState({
    value: 'foo2',
    posts: data.value,
})
```

.

This results in the following code. Also, your fetch belongs into the `componentDidMount()` function (I missed that in my first draft).

```
export default class Widget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            posts: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:8888/test-site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({posts: data.value}))

    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>value: {this.state.posts}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

For this special example, you might also want to use functional components with a `useState()` and a `useEffect` hook:

```
export default function Widget() {

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:8888/test-site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => setPosts(data.value))
    });


    return (
        <div>
            <p>value: {posts}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that code does not work but it does give me errors which I have added to my question.

Comment: yes, that's my fault. `this.state.posts` need to be defined, so it can be read in the first render, as the `fetch` result will be rendered in a later render call.

Comment: still no :( I updated my question with my code, 'posts' seems to be coming back undefined (as you can see from the console) but I went to the URL in a browser and it definitely returns a JSON String so I don't know why that is blank.  I also tried changing `componentWillMount()` to `componentDidMount()` but it returns the same results.  I'm not sure what else to try though.

Comment: Are you sure, `data.value` is defined. If I query my own Blog, there is no `value` key in the response. `data` on my wordpress API is an Array. Can you check that?

Comment: I did a few experiments and discovered more about the problem.  I updated both the text of my question and my code above.